# Mostrar Valor de BD en SELECT en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, select

Buenos Dias, en el codigo que muestro a continuacion quiero mostrar el valor que tiene un campo guardado en una BD Mysql en una lista SELECT en php

Codigo:

```
<form name="fe" action="" method="post">
        <table border="2">
            <tbody><tr><td>Nombre de Usuario</td>
            <td><input name="txtbus" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="btn1" value="Buscar" type="submit" onsubmit="this.reset()"></td></tr>
    </form>
<?php
$btn = "";
if(isset($_POST["btn1"])){
    $btn=$_POST["btn1"];
    $bus=$_POST["txtbus"];
if($btn=="Buscar"){
require_once('config.php');
            $mysqli = mysqli_init();
            $mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);      $mysqli->real_connect($config['db_host'],$config['db_user'],$config['db_password'],$config['db_name']);
$queryM = "SELECT nombre_usuario,nombre,idnivel,idservicio,idestado, servicio,estado,nivel
          FROM usuario,servicio,estado,nivel WHERE nombre_usuario = '$bus' and 
          idservicio = servicio.id and
          idestado   = estado.id and
          idnivel    = nivel.id ORDER BY usuario.id";
          $result    = $mysqli->query($queryM);
?>  
<form class='contacto'>
            <div><etiqueta>Nombre de Usuario:</etiqueta><input type='text' value='<?php echo $row['nombre_usuario']?>'></div>
            <div><etiqueta>Empleado:</etiqueta><input type='text' value='<?php echo $row['nombre']?>'></div>
            <div>
                <etiqueta>Nivel</etiqueta>
                <select id="nivel" name="nivel">
                        <?php 
                            $result2 = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM nivel');
                            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array())
                                {
                                echo'<OPTION VALUE="'.$row2['id'].'">'.$row2['nivel'].'</OPTION>';
                                }
                                $mysqli->close();
                        ?> 
                    </select>   
            </div>
            <div><etiqueta>Tipo de Servicio:</etiqueta><input type='text' value='<?php echo $row['servicio']?>'></div>
            <div><etiqueta>Estatus:</etiqueta><input type='text' value='<?php echo $row['estado']?>'></div>
            <!--<div><label>Estatus:</label><textarea rows='6'></textarea></div>-->
            <a id="cancelupdate" class="button delete" onsubmit="this.reset()">Cancelar</a>
            <div><input type='submit' value='Envia Mensaje' onsubmit="this.reset()"></div>
        </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Todos los datos se muestran, pero quiero que en el SELECT Option me muestre el valor que efectivamente esta guardado en la BD.

Tablas:
CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_usuario` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(72) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `idnivel` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `idservicio` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `idestado` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `nivel` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `nivel` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `servicio` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `servicio` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `estado` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Podrías ser más específico ?

Comment: hola, en la consulta a la BD quiero mostrar el valor que efectivamente tiene el campo "nivel" en un COMBO SELECT

Comment: en el codigo que tengo solo hago un recorrido a la tabla que contiene los codigos del campo "nivel" que estan en otra tabla, pero lo que quiero es mostrar el valor que efectivamente el usuario tiene en la BD

Comment: ¿Te refieres a cuando recorres el `$result2`  que no te muestra el valor de la columna `nivel`?  ¿Estás seguro de que esa consulta está arrojando datos? ¿Da error? ¿Qué error? ¿Estás verificando que la conexión a la base de datos es válida? ... No dejes que adivinemos todo cuando preguntas...

Comment: la tabla que recorre $result2 es la tabla "nivel" que no es la que quiero mostrar pero que estoy usando porque no he podido conseguir que muestre el valor que tiene ese dato en la tabla "usuario".

Comment: la conexion esta bien y la consulta no arroja ningun error, es simplemente que quiero mostrar en ese SELECT el valor que tiene el campo "idnivel" en la tabla "usuario"

Comment: Es que hay que sacarte la información con cucharita como se suele decir. Todavía no termino de entender de dónde quieres sacar el valor, si es de la consulta `$queryM` entonces debes construir el option como lo tienes ahora, pero recorriendo el contenido de `$result` y no de `$result2` como lo tienes ahora. Algo así: `while($row2 = $result->fetch_array())
                                {
                                echo'<OPTION VALUE="'.$row2['idnivel'].'">'.$row2['nivel'].'</OPTION>';
                                }`

Comment: muy bien, si hago el recorrido del contenido de $result, ¿como hago para mostrar el valor del campo "nivel" en el SELECT? esa es la pregunta

Comment: Voy a escribirte una respuesta basada además en consultas preparadas, ya que tu código no es seguro. Para la consulta SQL implementaré el uso de `JOIN` que dará más claridad al código.

Comment: perfecto, aunque lo resolvi usando lo propuesto por el amigo Triby, me gustaria conocer tu propuesta sobre seguridad, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del while analiza el valor que tiene el usuario; suponiendo que es idnivel:

```
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array())
{
    $sel = ($row['idnivel'] == $row2['id']) ? ' selected' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"{$row2['id']}\"$sel>{$row2['nivel']}</option>";
}
```

Si no estás trabajando con HTML5 entonces en vez de ' selected' deberías poner ' selected="selected"'.

Recuerda que todas las etiquetas HTML (independientemente de la versión) y sus atributos deben escribirse en minúsculas.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi propuesta, tomando en cuenta lo dicho en mis comentarios.

Omití el segundo SELECT, porque entendí que no era necesario para los fines de tu programa. También podrías considerar seleccionar menos campos en tu consulta SQL, si no los vas a necesitar.

```
<form name="fe" action="" method="post">
        <table border="2">
            <tbody><tr><td>Nombre de Usuario</td>
            <td><input name="txtbus" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="btn1" value="Buscar" type="submit" onsubmit="this.reset()"></td></tr>
    </form>
<?php
$btn = "";
if(isset($_POST["btn1"])){
    $btn=$_POST["btn1"];
    $bus=$_POST["txtbus"];

    if($btn=="Buscar"){

        require_once('config.php');
        $mysqli = mysqli_init();
        $mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        $mysqli->real_connect($config['db_host'],$config['db_user'],$config['db_password'],$config['db_name']);

        if ($mysqli){
            $queryM = 
                    "SELECT u.nombre_usuario, u.nombre, u.idnivel, s.idservicio, 
                            e.idestado, s.servicio, e.estado, n.nivel
                      FROM usuario u 
                      INNER JOIN servicio s ON u.idservicio = s.id 
                      INNER JOIN estado e ON u.idestado   = e.id
                      INNER JOIN nivel n ON u.idnivel    = n.id
                      WHERE u.nombre_usuario = ?
                      ORDER BY u.id";
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($queryM);
            if ($stmt){

              $stmt->bind_param("s",$bus);
              $stmt->execute();
              $stmt->bind_result($nombre_usuario, $nombre, $idnivel, $idservicio, $idestado, $servicio, $estado, $nivel);   
?>  
            <form class='contacto'>
            <div><etiqueta>Nombre de Usuario:</etiqueta><input type='text' value='<?php echo $row['nombre_usuario']?>'></div>
            <div><etiqueta>Empleado:</etiqueta><input type='text' value='<?php echo $row['nombre']?>'></div>
            <div>
                <etiqueta>Nivel</etiqueta>
                <select id="nivel" name="nivel">
<?php 
              while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo "<option value=\"$idnivel\">$nivel</option>";
              } 
              $stmt->close();
?> 
            </select>   
            </div>
            <div><etiqueta>Tipo de Servicio:</etiqueta><input type='text' value='<?php echo $row['servicio']?>'></div>
            <div><etiqueta>Estatus:</etiqueta><input type='text' value='<?php echo $row['estado']?>'></div>
            <!--<div><label>Estatus:</label><textarea rows='6'></textarea></div>-->
            <a id="cancelupdate" class="button delete" onsubmit="this.reset()">Cancelar</a>
            <div><input type='submit' value='Envia Mensaje' onsubmit="this.reset()"></div>
        </form>
<?php
      }else{

          echo "Error en la consulta SQL";

      }
              $mysqli->close();

}else{

        echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";  
}

    }else{

        echo "Opción buscar no fue seleccionada"; //Esta comprobación se puede omitir o cambiar por otra cosa

    }

}else{

    echo "btn1 no presionado";

}
```

Comment: Muy bien, voy a implementarlo y te cuento que tal, gracias

Comment: @HGarcia *un par de cosas* pueden ser *millones* de cosas si no especificas.

Comment: dame un minuto por favor que aun estoy novato en este foro y todavia estoy adaptandome a su funcionamiento

Comment: la consulta que me diste funciona bien en phpmyadmin pero al hacerla en php pasa lo siguiente: ok la consulta funciona bien desde phpmyadmin, pero desde php  pasa lo siguiente:                                                 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo "<option value=\"$idnivel\">$nivel</option>";
              } 
              $stmt->close();  efectivamente me muestra el valor de la bd, pero solo unicamente ese valor, sin las demas opciones

Comment: y lo otro es: ¿como hacer esa misma rutina para los otros campos, "servicio" y "estado"? y gracias por tu ayuda hermano, me ha sido muy util como aprendizaje

Comment: @HGarcia si te fijas bien en el código, hay esta línea: `$stmt->bind_result($nombre_usuario, $nombre, $idnivel, $idservicio, $idestado, $servicio, $estado, $nivel);`, lo que hace ese método es vincular a cada variable las diferentes columnas del `SELECT...`  entonces, tú puedes usar esas variables para lo que quieras, sea para construir diferentes `select` con cada una, sea para combinarlas, etc. Si quieres otro `select` con cualquiera de esas variables sólo lo creas dentro del `while`... sólo que al tener más de un select tendrás que usar dos variables para ir concatenando cada uno.

Comment: ok muchas gracias por tu ayuda, voy a estudiar un poco sobre sentencias preparadas que no lo tengo muy claro todavia,gracias

Comment: De nada @HGarcia, si la respuesta ha solucionado el problema planteado puedes marcarla para que no aparezca como no resuelta. Cuando puedas lee el apartado [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta a mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en la ayuda del sitio.